# How can I split the hashmap I have and get the information?

Tags: java, hashmap

I have an input output like this. A maximum of three elements can come in the targetInfo in this output. I want to get the first three elements in it. So I want to print the **entertainment_interest_f, citizenship_s, tv_interest_f** variables and values ​​to the screen. How can I do it?

```
CollectiveInterestsRes(
                            targetInfo=[{entertainment_interest_f=3.0}, {citizenship_s->America=3.0}, {tv_interest_f=3.0}],
                            msisdnCount=3,
                            msisdnList=[495012072622, 495012103468, 495012115405],
                            isSuccess=true,
                            ruleRequests=[RuleRequest(ruleId=tv, subruleId=null, locationRequest=null, operator=EQ, values=[1], msisdnRequest=null)]
                        )
```

Class content like this :

```
public class CollectiveInterestsRes {
        private List<Map<String,String>> targetInfo;
    
        private Integer gsmNoCount;
        private List<String> gsmNoList;
        private boolean isSuccess;
        private List<RuleRequest> ruleRequests;
    }
```

I was able to break the method down so much, can you help me for more?

```
List<Map<String, String>> targetInfo = collectiveInterestsRes.get(0).getTargetInfo();
```

Comment: A `List<Map<String, String>>` is a waste over a `Map<String, String>` if your entry keys are unique. From what I'm seeing here, I would assume that `CollectiveInterestsRes` is a `Map` itself, which you could `map.get("targetInfo")` to start things off. Keep in mind a hashmap is inherently unordered, you need _keys_ to retrieve information.

Comment: So how can i do this can you show one example? I've never worked with hashmap before so I'm very unfamiliar..

Comment: You should refer to the [documentation for Map](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html). Oracle's [tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/interfaces/map.html) also covers them extensively.

Comment: @Rogue how do you understand that the provided object is a map? And how is this connected to the given question?

Comment: @m.antkowicz in the same manner that the state of any object has a 1:1 correspondence to a `Map` (field names => object values). The manner of using `.get(0)` on `collectiveInterestsRes` made me assume they had an unserialized object. There is a direct approach to just grabbing the info outright, but my concern was that it was potentially furthering a poor design.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apart of refactoring this little bit crazy structure you have, the thing you can do is to iterate over the list and put all elements in one common map. Then access elements by key

```
final List<Map<String, String>> targetInfo = collectiveInterestsRes.get(0).getTargetInfo();
final Map<String, String> accumulatedMap = new HashMap<>();

targetInfo.forEach(accumulatedMap::putAll);

System.out.println(accumulatedMap.get("tv_interest_f"));
System.out.println(accumulatedMap.get("entertainment_interest_f"));
```

Comment: This was the answer I was looking for. Actually if I knew the hashmap structure maybe I could do it too, thank you very much!